# How do I determine if a beanstalkd tube is empty?

Tags: message-queue, distributed-computing, beanstalkd

By "empty" I mean there's no job ready to be reserved or being reserved.

I've read the [document](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt#L546) on github and find that `stats` is almost what I want except that it gives information about the whole system, not a specific tube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to run, and parse the output from the [stats-tube [tubename]](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/master/doc/protocol.md#stats-tube-command) command. It returns the number of jobs in the tube of each type (urgent, ready, reserved, delayed, and others), and other tube-specific information.